# Columna ambigua en query de sql

Tags: sql

Hola estaba haciendo una query simple en sql server y tengo este problema:

```
SELECT [OrdenID]  <---columna ambigua
  ,[Producto]
  ,[FechaOrden]
  ,[Cantidad]
FROM [KentFoods].[dbo].[DetalleOrden],[Ordenes],[Productos]
```

La columna OrdenID dice que es ambigua ya que en la tabla **Ordenes** y en la tabla **DetalleOrden** ambas tienen la columna **OrdenID**

Me gustaria saber como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: Usa alias, como te digo en mi respuesta. Pero otra cosa: esa consulta no te va a servir, debes indicar la relación entre las tablas. Lo ideal es que uses JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ponle un alias a las tablas, y selecciona el campo OrdenID indicando el alias.

```
SELECT o.[OrdenID]
  ,[Producto]
  ,[FechaOrden]
  ,[Cantidad]
FROM [KentFoods].[dbo].[DetalleOrden] do, [Ordenes] o, [Productos] p
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que ponerle un alias a las tablas. Luego en el select le indicas el atributo de qué tabla lo querés obtener. Por ej.:

```
SELECT detalle.[OrdenID]
  ,[Producto]
  ,[FechaOrden]
  ,[Cantidad]
FROM [KentFoods].[dbo].[DetalleOrden] detalle,[Ordenes] orden,[Productos]
```

o

```
SELECT orden.[OrdenID]
  ,[Producto]
  ,[FechaOrden]
  ,[Cantidad]
FROM [KentFoods].[dbo].[DetalleOrden] detalle,[Ordenes] orden,[Productos]
```

De todas formas te comento que ese query no te va a devolver la información que precisás. Necesitás hacer un join con las tablas.